# How to cut the log file?

Tags: node.js, pm2

Im using [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2) to create log file and it is very big(about 1.2GB, and it is still increasing).

How to cut a big log file to multiple small log files?

Has pm2 support anyway to cut the log file automatically?

Answer (score 2):

In general, you do not have to worry if pm2 allows rotating log files because you can do that on a linux based system using the `logrotate` utility.

More details can be found at the following:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-log-files-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-12-10

http://www.z-car.com/blog/programming/how-to-rotate-logs-using-pm2-process-manager-for-node-js

https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/114

Answer (score 0):

As an example:

`var file = fs.readFileSync('logfile.log')
if (file.length > 1024) { // 1KB
  fs.writeFileSync('logfile.log', file.slice(-1024))
}`